# Are empty loops with side effects in it's condition caught by dead code elimination?

Tags: java, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot, dead-code

Given the following code

```
var cachedInt = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(xxxxx);

while(true){
   while(cachedInt.offer(randomProvider.nextInt()));
   latch.await();
}
```

Will the jvm eventually eliminate the while loop because it has no body or does it recognize the side effect of the condition and keep the loop in place?

Comment: empty loop? `while(true) {}` is not empty loop and it will run endlessly

Comment: @ByeBye I was talking about the inner while loop

Comment: No the jvm will not "optimize" your method call away. Your condition will run repeatedly until it returns `false` and the side effects will happen as normal.

Comment: Thank you. If you create an answer I'll go ahead and accept it

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer. Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the jvm will not "optimize" your method call away. Your condition will run repeatedly until it returns false and the side effects will happen as normal.